# Func в LINQ. Почему нет ошибки?

Tags: c#, linq

Немного не догоняю.
Вот в GroupBy описано, что я могу подать на вход функцию `System.Func<TSource, TKey>`.

Тем не менее, если я подам функцию с 3 и более элементами, то компилятор ее успешно проглотит.

Хотя в описании метода написано, что ожидается функция, которая принимает 1 элемент. Так и должно быть или я что-то путаю?

Ну допустим такой глупый пример:

```
new[] {"1", "2", "3"}.GroupBy(x => Test(x, "1", "1"));

  static string Test(string p1, string p2, string p3)
        {
            return "";
        }
```

Хотя написано, что требуется функция 1 параметра:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваша функция от одного аргумента (x), и возвращает одно значение. Так что это всё ещё `Func<T, U>`.

Действительно, лямбда-выражение

```
x => Test(x, "1", "1")
```

можно представить себе как такую функцию:

```
string f(string x)
{
    return Test(x, "1", "1");
}
```

и GroupBy запишется как

```
new[] {"1", "2", "3"}.GroupBy(f);
```

Мы видим, что функция `f` от одного строкового аргумента, а то, что внутри неё вызывается функция от трёх аргументов, не играет никакой роли.

Comment: Хм... Не подумал об этом.